# Kinectv2 for windows compatible with xbox one

Tags: kinect, xbox, xbox-one

Is the kinectv2 for windows compatible with xbox one? I cannot seem to get my xbox one to recognize that it is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Now if the charger indicator goes green then power supply is ok. Still you will have to use a small software to check if every thing works fine. Go with these tutorials and run a check.[getting started with Kinect](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Getting-started-with-Kinect-development-quickly-with-the-Kinect-for-Windows-Quickstart-Series)